# Is this a correct way to think about Bayes Rule?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem

We know that in probability theory that if events $A, B$ are independent of each other, then the probability of them both happening is
$$
P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B).
$$

For Bayes Rule we know that
$$
P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)\cdot P(B).
$$

Does this mean that we can think of it as a correction that the probabilities $P(B)$ and $P(A|B)$ are independent of each other, or an extension of the original rule?

Comment: The first equation defines independence of events, whereas the second equation with $P(B)\neq0$ defines the conditional probability $P(A|B).$ Taken together, we see that $P(A|B)=P(A)$ if and only if events $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

The word "independence" is used to describe events, not probabilities, so it doesn't make sense to say that two probabilities $\mathbb P(B)$ and $\mathbb P(A|B)$ are independent. You can think of it as if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A|B)$, as the probability of $A$ occurring does not change whether or not $B$ occurs. So we have $$\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(A|B)\mathbb P(B)$$
as $\mathbb P(A)=\mathbb P(A|B)$.